# Grid view binded with a text box unable to show results

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, gridview, dataset, dataadapter

i'm trying to bind a search textBox ( that uses a Stored Procedure ) with a grid view but when ever i run them and type the search condition ,no results are displayed and the GridView it self dosent show . i tried many ways including using a DataAdapter & DataSet to fill the results of the search textBox and then bind the DataSet to the GridView. but it didnt work either here is the code:

```
 protected void SearchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    try

    {

    string con_str = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(con_str);

    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("dbo.SearchRecords", con);
    com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    SqlParameter pDocumentTitle = new SqlParameter("@Doc_Title", SearchTextBox.Text);
    SqlParameter pUserID = new SqlParameter("@User_ID", SearchTextBox.Text);
    SqlParameter pDocumentType = new SqlParameter("@Doc_Type", SearchTextBox.Text);
    SqlParameter pDocumentDescription = new SqlParameter("@Doc_Description",SearchTextBox.Text);

    com.Parameters.Add(pDocumentTitle);
    com.Parameters.Add(pUserID);
    com.Parameters.Add(pDocumentType);
    com.Parameters.Add(pDocumentDescription);

    con.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter DA = new SqlDataAdapter(com); 
    com.ExecuteNonQuery();

    DataSet t = new DataSet();
    DA.Fill(t);

    GridView1.DataBind();

    GridView1.DataSource = t;


    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    Label2.Text = ex.Message;
    //throw;
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong but don't you need to call DataBind() after you have set the DataSource property? e.g.

```
GridView1.DataSource = t;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change the order of binding as follow...Always write DataBind() after assigning the DataSource to Any DataControl

```
GridView1.DataSource = t;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: thank you very much @Amol Kolekar it worked really well :)
but now i`m facing another problem lol

Answer (score 0):

datasource must define first ,then do the binding

```
    GridView1.DataSource = t;
    GridView1.DataBind();
```